# Authentication error with twitter like bot in python

Tags: python, tweepy, twitter-oauth, twitterapi-python

Hi Im trying to create a twitter like bot, that likes post with specific hashtags.
But I am getting unauthenticated error even though I am using the right keys.

raise Unauthorized(response)                                                                                        tweepy.errors.Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized                                                                            Unauthorized
This is the code I am using:

```
# Importing Tweepy and time
import tweepy
import time

# Credentials (INSERT YOUR CREDENTIALS BELOW)
all_keys = open("twitterkeys.txt", "r").read().splitlines()
api_key = all_keys[0]
api_key_secret = all_keys[1]
access_token = all_keys[2]
access_token_secret = all_keys[3]

# Gainaing access and connecting to Twitter API using Credentials
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token, api_key, api_key_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)

auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(api_key, api_key_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Bot searches for tweets containing certain keywords
class MyStream(tweepy.StreamingClient):

    # This function gets called when a tweet passes the stream
    def on_tweet(self, tweet):

        #Liking the tweet
        try:
            client.like(tweet.id)
            print(tweet.text)

        except Exception as error:
            print(error)
        
        # delay between tweets
        time.sleep(1)

# Creating Stream object
stream = MyStream(bearer_token=bearer_token)

# Adding terms to search rules
stream.add_rules(tweepy.StreamRule("(#Python OR #programming) (-is:retweet -is:reply)"))

# Starting stream
stream.filter()
```

Does anyone know why Im getting unauthenticated error?
Perhaps is because I am using OAuth 1.0a?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import tweepy
import time
all_keys = open("twitterkeys.txt", "r").read().splitlines()
api_key = all_keys[0]
api_key_secret = all_keys[1]
access_token = all_keys[2]
access_token_secret = all_keys[3]
auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(api_key, api_key_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
class MyStream(tweepy.Stream):
    def on_status(self, status):
        try:
            api.create_favorite(status.id)
            print(status.text)
        except Exception as error:
            print(error)
        time.sleep(1)
stream = MyStream(auth, listener=MyStream())
stream.filter(track=["#Python", "#programming"], filter_level='medium')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).